# onfocusout on some specific fields using jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin to validate my form. I have a pair of origin and destination city and a pair of start and end date in my form. I want the `onfocusout` function to work only on airport fields when they have same code in both.

My code below...

```
$(function () {
    var validator = $("#testForm").validate({
        errorClass: "errorMsg",
        errorElement: "span",
        rules: {
            fromAirport: {
                "required": true,
                "onfocusout": true
            },
            toAirport: {
                "required": true,
                "onfocusout": true
            },
            fromDate: {
                "required": true,
                "onfocusout": false
            }
            toDate: {
                "required": true,
                "onfocusout": false
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fromAirport: {
                "required": "fromAirportis required!"
            },
            toAirport: {
                "required": "toAirportis required!"
            }
            fromDate: {
                "required": "fromDateis required!"
            },
            toDate: {
                "required": "toDate is required!"
            },
        },
        onfocusout: function(el) {
            if (!this.checkable(el)){
                this.element(el);
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
        }
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4yegctz5/1/**

Comment: Can you create a `DEMO`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4yegctz5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Regarding this code...

   ```
   onfocusout: function(el) {
       if (!this.checkable(el)){
           this.element(el);
       }
   },
   ```

What is `checkable`?  There is [no such thing represented in this plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/?s=checkable).

2. Regarding this code...

   ```
   rules: {
       fromAirport: {
           "required": true,
           "onfocusout": true // <- No such rule
       }, ...
   ```

`"onfocusout"` is not a rule.  It's only a callback function that's triggered by an "event" within the form.  Additionally, although you can create any custom rule, you cannot create a custom rule that affects the validation events.

---

> OP's Title:  *"onfocusout on some specific fields using jQuery Validate"*

Your only solution would be to over-ride the `onfocusout` function as follows.  I simply placed an arbitrary `class` on any field that you want to be evaluated on the `onfocusout` event.  Then the custom `onfocusout` function uses a conditional to check the element for this class and then trigger validation.

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('ofo')) {
        this.element(element);
    }
},
```

**DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/4yegctz5/3/**